# Client event of telerik grid

Tags: jquery, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using telerik grid as below

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnSubmitChanges("Grid_onSubmitChanges"))
%>
```

Here OnSubmitChange event has 3 fields

inserted - an array of data items which have been inserted.

updated - an array of data items which have been updated.

deleted - an array of data items which have been deleted.

but what if i want to select already exist rows from grid, which user didnt update or delete
OnSubmitChange event doesn't provide those rows.

Comment: I don't think you have this option by default. But since you know which items are on the grid, can you query again, then remove the inserted, updated and deleted rows from the results?

Comment: The event is called `OnSubmitChange`, so obviously, the records that have not been changed are not in the event.

Comment: @ataravati Then how can I get unchanged records from grid when submit the changes? any idea?